# How to develop a Sonar plugin for a new language using gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, sonarqube

I am currently developing a Sonar plugin for a new language; for me developing the parser for the language is, in fact, the easy part.

It is the rest I have trouble with, and the first road block is Sonar's [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Coding+a+Plugin), which only covers Maven.

But I use gradle.

The example in the documentation is also quite troubling, since the very first lines of the pom.xml extract are:

```
<artifactId>sonar-foo-plugin</artifactId>
<!-- CUSTOM PACKAGING!! -->
<packaging>sonar-plugin</packaging>
```

Now, I don't know much about maven and really, I would like to avoid "switching back" to it; one reason being that I currently do things with gradle which maven simply cannot do, save for delegating to ant.

My hunch so far is that this custom packaging is defined by Sonar's [sonar-packaging-maven-plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar/sonar-packaging-maven-plugin); now, what is that supposed to mean? How do I replicate this plugin with gradle? Where do I start?

And while Sonar plugins do exist for gradle, they only cover the analysis part, not the plugin development. My "web searching" so far (using [Duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com)) failed to turn anything useful...

Comment: I'd just reverse engineer the mentioned plugin and write it as normal configurable jar task - maybe it can be done that way. What's specific about sonar packaging?

Comment: @Opal heh, if I knew... But I'm starting to get help from the dev mailing list, so I'll probably come up with something